# How to get $_GET['id'] when using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

It should be only the id number but it has `profile/` prefix now which broke everything.

This is the rule I use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /v0\.3/profile/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /v0.3/profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule profile/(.+)$ /v0.3/profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```